# How to UPDATE and set values to a column in a sub-query on the same table

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble getting this SQL to work. Basically I want to `UPDATE` the column `sort_order` and set it to the `parents_sort_order` which is selected by a subquery on the same table. Here's my `SELECT` query showing the data I need....

```
SELECT p.id,p.sort_order,p.parent_id, (
  SELECT `sort_order` AS parent_sort_order
  FROM `product`
  WHERE id = p.parent_id
)
FROM  `product` p
WHERE p.dealer_id !=0
AND p.vendor_id >100
```

Thanks!

Comment: General rule is that you can't update a table that you're selecting from in the same query. It's like fixing a floor while standing in the middle of it. At some point there'll be a hole under your feet and down you go.

Comment: Love the analogy..lol, ya noticed that, do you think the only way is to script this out?

Comment: Yeah, two part query is about the only option.

Comment: I know I could easily whip up a PHP script to get this task done, but I want to better my SQL skills, how would this be done in a 2 part query?

Comment: Why dont you do a JOIN query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join version of your select:

```
SELECT p.id,p.sort_order,p.parent_id, b.sort_order as parent_sort_order
FROM  `product` p join `product` b
on p.id = b.parent_id
WHERE p.dealer_id !=0
AND p.vendor_id >100
```

Update Option 1:

```
update product a, product b set a.sort_order = b.parent_sort_order
where a.id = b.parent_id
and a.dealer_id !=0
and a.vendor_id > 100
```

Update Option 2:

```
update product a left join product b on a.id = b.parent_id 
set a.sort_order = b.parent_sort_order
where a.dealer_id !=0
and a.vendor_id > 100
```

Comment: sweet! had no idea you could JOIN the same table--never though of playing with target names... gonna test after lunch, but sure you got it--thanks!